# Is Javascript/jQuery aware of CSS formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is sort of a general question.. but I first learned CSS heavily, then started experimenting more with custom JavaScript and jQuery. I've been having a great time with JavaScript and jQuery noticing they are a nice next step when dealing with classes and ID's and manipulating how they work... although it just dawned on me.. it seems as though CSS is very specific and can put things anywhere and do anything with them.. do you know if JavaScript and jQuery are aware of what the CSS styles are? Or does JavaScript and jQuery just inspect parents and siblings regardless of styles? I'm trying to visualize what Javascript and jQuery are thinking and doing. I have 'Inspect Element' for Chrome/Firefox and that helps me visualize what the CSS is doing.

Maybe a better question is.. what is a good tool to help me see and debug what Javascript and jQuery are doing? I'm kind of shooting blank and hitting refresh constantly after changing my code to see results. There has to be a better way. Help!

Comment: browser developer tools - F12

Comment: jQuery mostly just manipulates the DOM. But it has selectors `:hidden` and `:visible` that examines CSS to determine if the element is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use developers tools from browser for debugging jQuery/Javascript by adding breakpoints :

### Chrome

1. Open the browser.
2. From the menu, select tools.
3. From tools, choose developer tools.
4. Finally, select Console.

### Firefox Firebug

1. Open the browser.
2. Go to the web page:
3. http://www.getfirebug.com
4. Follow the instructions
5. how to install Firebug

### Internet Explorer

1. Open the browser.
2. From the menu, select tools.
3. From tools, choose developer tools.
4. Finally, select Console.

Answer (score 0):

1. [JSHint](http://jshint.com/): 
   JSHint is a community-driven tool to detect errors and potential problems in JavaScript code and to enforce your team’s coding conventions. It is very flexible so you can easily adjust it to your particular coding guidelines and the environment you expect your code to execute in.
2. [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) (In case you want to debug JSON):
   JSON Formatter created to help with debugging. As JSON data is often output without line breaks to save space, it is extremely difficult to actually read and make sense of it. This little tool hoped to solve the problem by formatting the JSON data so that it is easy to read and debug by human beings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this,
Javascript is the logical/programmable part of the page. Where you can define behaviour.

CSS is about visual properties of each element.

HTML provides elements on the page, JS can be used to design custom elements.

On `Chrome/Firefox/IE` hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to open developer tools, there open `Console` tab, in console you can execute `JS`.